# Get a post's text, from the Stack Exchange API, in decoded and pastable form?

Tags: support, markdown, api

I know how to retrieve `body_markdown` with the Stack Exchange API. But if I copy the retrieved body into a Markdown editor then I don't get back the "real" body of the answer. I've tried using stackedit.io, Github's editor and I have even tried to copy the body into the edit page of the answer itself. But I don't get back the "real" answer.

For example, I receive 2 newlines in `body_markdown` with the API as:

```
\r\n\r\n
```

But no Markdown editor will transform this into 2 real newlines.

Ok, so answering to the comments, I made an example showing that the markdown I receive from the API is not complete(or not correct):

```js
$.getJSON (
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/2353416?site=stackoverflow&filter=!-W2dp-oiHRff49soT1df",
    data => {console.log (data.items[0].body_markdown);}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now if I copy the markdown body back into StackEdit or I paste it into the "edit" page of the question itself, I receive some garbage, it is not converted back to the original question.

How can I get back the "real", correct body(no markdown, no HTML)?

Comment: How is it transformed then?

Comment: that's what I'm asking

Comment: I meant: what is wrong and/or what do you expect. It depends on where those newlines are if they are rendered or not. Maybe include the example post you used so we can re-create.

Comment: @rene this is the post itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353416/no-module-named-urls and the API response: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=2353416&filter=!9Z(-wtr.v&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: @rene I updated my question with an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), under ***General***:

> All API responses are JSON,...

So this means that your program must `JSON.parse` the results somehow -- which will actualize all of that `\n`, `\r`, etc. text into the appropriate char codes.

For example:

```js
$.getJSON (
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/316603?site=meta&filter=!-W2dp-oiHRff49soT1df",
    data => {console.log (data.items[0].body_markdown);}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Run that, and you will see copy and pastable markdown text in the console.

---

#### Text with [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

In many cases, editor inputs handle HTML entities smoothly. EG you enter `&clubs;` and "♣" is rendered and stored properly.

But for some editors, or for preformatted code, the entities need to be decoded/unescaped.

For example, in javascript:

```js
$.getJSON (
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/2353416?site=stackoverflow&filter=!-W2dp-oiHRff49soT1df",
    data => {
        var rawMarkdown = htmlDecode (data.items[0].body_markdown);
        console.log (rawMarkdown);}
);

function htmlDecode (textWithHtmlEntities) {
    var tmpDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString (textWithHtmlEntities, "text/html");
    return tmpDoc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

-- which yields text with the code blocks as expected.

Comment: your answer seems to work with my question but does not work with other ones(please check my updated question - I made an example with your code but another post id)

Comment: @Csaba, for code blocks, you also need to decode any HTML entities. See the updated answer.

Comment: wow, thank you very much, this really works, I am so happy now, you made my day happier :)

Comment: @Csaba, You're welcome; glad to help.

Comment: Note to self: Investigate ["unsafe" filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) for this.  Strips out HTML entities, but what else?